# SQL INSERT INTO table(a, b , c) VALUES (:a, :b, :c, SELECT ...)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to insert 4 values into a table. I'm getting 3 values from POST and the other one I want to get it from another table. This is how I thought about implementing it but it doesn't seem to be working. Any suggestions?

```
$query = "INSERT INTO topics (subject, data, uid, role) VALUES (:user, :pass, :uid, SELECT role FROM users WHERE uid=:uid) ";
```

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO topics (subject, data, uid, role) SELECT :user, :pass:, :uid, role FROM users WHERE uid=:uid)";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, all subqueries need to be surrounded by their own parentheses.  So, you can fix your query by using:

```
INSERT INTO topics (subject, data, uid, role)
    VALUES (:user, :pass, :uid, (SELECT role FROM users WHERE uid = :uid));
```

Personally, I much prefer the `INSERT . . . SELECT` version of `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO topics (subject, data, uid, role)
    SELECT :user, :pass, :uid, u.role
    FROM users u
    WHERE uid = :uid;
```

Comment: Ah silly mistake on my end. Thank you!
I will be using the second version from now on.